# Google Analytics SDK creates SQLite errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

## Updates

**19th August 2015** -  Bug seems to have now been fixed in the `3.13` update, even though the only thing they list in their changelog is `"Fixed an issue which caused crashes when using setCampaignParametersFromUrl"`. Take that as you will.

**8th June 2015** -  Still encountering this problem. If I disable automatic sending of events (`[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = -1;`) then I still receive errors. I assume, therefore, that the problem lies with inserting the event into the Google Analytics SQLite database, that somehow my own database statement that is currently in progress are becoming `void`.

**10th June 2015** -  Still encountering crashes. Tried removing my controllers extending `GAITrackedViewController` and sending the `createScreenView` track manually with no change in crash frequency.

**25th June 2015** - Still encountering crashes.

---

## Intro

I have added the `Google Analytics SDK 3.12` to my iPhone app and everything is working as expected - I run the app and can see all of the hits and events that I have setup coming through on the Web interface.

I am initialising the SDK in my `AppDelegate` right at the top of my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, like so:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID];
```

---

## The problem

However, I have found that running Google Analytics creates errors when I try and use SQLite for myself. They can manifest as serious errors such as:

- `"Database disk image is malformed"` and then insta-crashes
- `"Disc i/O error"` whenever I run a query (though doesn't crash)

And they can also cause my own SQLite queries to just fail, for instance:

```
if (! sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &_statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {`
    // ..
    // ..

    if (sqlite3_step(_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
```

Will result, randomly, in the following error:

`sqlite3_prepare_v2 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6800000000)`

If I comment out the SDK initialisation then everything goes back to being incredibly stable. Uncomment it again and it will crash the app within a minute.

---

## Pre-emptive question answering

1. Am running this on a iPhone 6 running 8.3 (12F70).
2. Have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app.
3. I have added all of the pre-requisites for Google Analytics to work; all of the `.m` files to the library, the `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a` file, and also the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.
4. I also have Crashlytics, but have tried commenting it out from the code (`[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];`) and removing its library from the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` with exactly the same results.

---

## Code

### Setting up the class

```
// In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
[Db setup];
[Db connect];
```

### Accesses the class

```
Db * db = [[Db alloc] init];

if ([db prepare:@"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ?" withBindings:@[@"123"]]) {
    while ([db stepThrough]) {
        // ..
    }
}

[db finalise];
```

### The class

*(Have indicated where the errors appear with comments)*

```
@implementation Db

static sqlite3  * _db;
static NSString * _dbPath;

#pragma mark - Setup

+ (BOOL)setup {
    NSString      * sqlBundlePath   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    NSString      * documentsFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString      * sqlDocumentPath = [[documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db"] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"];
    NSFileManager * fileManager     = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (! [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:sqlDocumentPath]) {
        NSError * error;
        BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sqlBundlePath toPath:sqlDocumentPath error:&error];

        if (! success) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    _dbPath = sqlDocumentPath;
    return YES;
}

+ (BOOL)connect {
    sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED);
    return sqlite3_open([_dbPath UTF8String], &_db);
}

#pragma mark - Querying

- (BOOL)prepare:(NSString *)sql withBindings:(NSArray *)bindings {
    // ERROR CAN OCCUR ON THE FOLLOWING LINE
    if (! sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &_statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Error whilst preparing query: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));
        sqlite3_finalize(_statement);
        return NO;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < [bindings count]; i++) {
        sqlite3_bind_text(_statement,
                          i + 1,
                          [bindings[i] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? [@"" UTF8String] : [bindings[i] UTF8String],
                          -1,
                          SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)stepThrough {
    // ERROR CAN OCCUR ON THE FOLLOWING LINE
    if (sqlite3_step(_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        return YES;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(_statement);
    return NO;
}

- (void)finalise {
    sqlite3_finalize(_statement);
}

@end
```

Comment: Seems that you are doing it the right way. Can you use another platform for analytics?

Comment: We would ideally like to use Google Analytics as we also use it for our website, so it will tie in with our conversion goals, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the new version of the SDK (`3.13`) fixed this issue (at least for me), even though their changelog does not specifically mention it.